# change color in yii using html

Tags: php, html, yii

how can i change the color of errors using HTML in the YII view?

### My code looks like this right now. I am not sure how the echo and html command can be used together.

foreach ($inventoryModelsAndResults as $result)

```
{
    echo implode(", ", $result["data"]) . "<br/>";
    echo $result["message"] . "<br/>";
    foreach ($result["model"]->getErrors() as $attribute => $errors) {
       echo  "Attribute $attribute has the following errors:" . "<br/>";
       echo "<ul>";
       foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo "<li>" . $error . "</li><br/>";
       }
       echo "</ul>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Why you don't use `errorSummary` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried this and it works.

```
<li style='color: red;'>
```

Comment: Don't Copy other's answers on the same post. [change color in yii using html](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34168082) This is really wrong and NAA.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ul>
  <li style='color:red;'>Hello world!</li>
</ul>
```

Actually you can just put into li tag something like this
`<li style='color:red;'>` btw, even I don't know Yii well your code doesn't looks well, you shouldn't use in views buisness, best way it's just to put varriables into the tags. As you see, I added snippet to show that it should change color of text inside li

Comment: it's quite strange because in this case it should show you red text, btw, check in browser if this css style works and nothing change the color of text. also working and good code it's two different things, you want for templates you can google some template engine for yii if it doesn't provided his own, for example i use in almost all my projects, twig or pure php.

Comment: actually the problem was with the quotes. "<li style='color: red;'>" . i tried this and it works.

Comment: hm, i didn't notice that if you want to put " to echo you need to use backslash, so does it works now? quite nice, btw i would like to advice to check some views like twig and so on, because display html like this isn't good way.

Comment: on the same code how can i count the total number of successful and failed data uploads? right now it will give me a color code if it fails in red but i want to be able to display total

Comment: @revuer1 it depends if $result["model"]->getErrors() array or object, but you can use something like this <?php echo sizeof( $result["model"]->getErrors()); ?>